# In react router when routing to another page it starts from the part where i left the previous page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am quite new to react-router, I  have this problem on a project where when I scroll down a page and then go to another page the other page start from the part where I left in the previous page but don't start from the top, so what might be the problem and its fixes?

[Link of the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-snow-rsbtg?file=/src/pages/contact.js)

**Page 1**
[image]

**Then Routing to next page**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function handleClick() {
  window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
}

export default function ElevateAppBar(props: Props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <ElevationScroll {...props}>
        <AppBar>
          <Toolbar className="toolbar">
            <Link onClick={handleClick} className="link" to="/">
              Home
            </Link>
            <Link onClick={handleClick} className="link">
              About
            </Link>
            <Link onClick={handleClick} to="/contact" className="link">
              Contact
            </Link>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </ElevationScroll>
      <Toolbar />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: aren't there another way, I mean from the react-router-dom

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can add the code I suggested to your navbar component and it should solve the issue.

Comment: You also are missing a route for your about page. (to="/about")

Comment: it was working, I think it didn't autosave my code that's why about route is missing